# Resource request: Hainanese dictionaries

Tags: topolect, resources, dictionary

What are the available Hainanese (海南話) dictionaries? In particular, dictionaries of the Wenchang (文昌) dialect. If those are not available, dictionaries of the Haikou (海口) dialect are also fine.

If not mistaken, the government in Guangdong once published a series of dictionaries of the languages of Guangdong, including Cantonese, Hakka, and Hainanese. However, I don't remember the name of the series. (EDIT: I was mistaken. I was thinking about [Guangdong Romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guangdong_Romanization) (廣東拼音方案) for Cantonese, Hakka, Hainanese, and Teochew)

Answer (score 2):

The [海口方言词典](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%B5%B7%E5%8F%A3%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/12155637) (Haikou Topolect Dictionary) is the go-to for Hainanese dictionaries. Part of the venerable [现代汉语方言大词典](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Dictionary_of_Modern_Chinese_Dialects) (*Great Dictionary of Modern Chinese Dialects*) series, it was published in 1996, and can be [accessed](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=bn%3A9787534328862&qt=notfound_page&search=Search) in libraries around the world. The transcription of sounds is done in IPA with Chao tone letters.

For Wenchang specifically, there is the [方言 chapter](http://www.hnszw.org.cn/data/news/2015/04/77216/) of the 文昌县志 (*Wenchang Annals*, I suppose), published in 2000 and also [found in libraries](https://www.worldcat.org/title/wenchang-xian-zhi/oclc/47926838&referer=brief_results). The related [dialect of Qionghai](https://www.worldcat.org/title/qionghai-xian-zhi/oclc/36343320&referer=brief_results) is also recorded in part 25 of its *Annals* ([琼海县志](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%90%BC%E6%B5%B7%E5%8E%BF%E5%BF%97)).

Otherwise you will have to glean vocabulary items from scientific journals and websites. E.g. the [海南闽语的语音研究](https://www.worldcat.org/title/hainan-minyu-de-yuyin-yanjiu/oclc/730474549&referer=brief_results), a study from 2006.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a book entitled:

- 《 一种方言在两地三代间的变异：文昌话和漳州话在本土与海外的时地差异 》

That you might be interested in.

It also looks like《方言》1986年第2期 has an article called:

- 海南岛文昌方言音系

I know this isn't really helpful but here's a horrible screenshot of a terrible picture:

> [image]